cumcount or cumsum with groupby and reset condition
I have a data frame with ID and Tag as columns.
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'Tag': ['', 'X', '', '', 'X', '','X']}  )  

The counts column starts from 0 and gradually increases in number in the order of 1 and 2. If the ID changes or there is an X on the tag, I want it to start again from 0.


You can check equal to 'X' in column 'Tag' with Series.eq and apply Series.cumsum, add the result to df.groupby alongside 'ID' and get groupby.cumcount:
df['Counts'] = (df.groupby(['ID', 
                            df['Tag'].eq('X').cumsum()])
                .cumcount()
                )

Output
  ID Tag  Counts
0  A           0
1  A   X       0
2  A           1
3  A           2
4  B   X       0
5  B           1
6  B   X       0

